# If $\ (X,d)\ $ is a complete metric space, and $\ A\ $ is a closed, convex subset of $\ X,\ $ then is $\ A\ $ connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, connectedness

Transparent note: I edited the question because it wasn't originally what I intended it to be.

> If $\ (X,d)\ $ is a complete metric space, and $\ A\ $ is a closed, convex
> subset of $\ X,\ $ then is $\ A\ $ connected?

[Definition of convex metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_metric_space): $(A,d)$ is convex if
\begin{multline*}
(a_1, a_2 \in A \text{ and } a_1 \ne a_2) \implies \\
\exists\ y\in A\setminus\{a_1,a_2\} \text{ such that } d(a_1, y) + d(y,a_2)= d(a_1, a_2).
\end{multline*}

We require $\ A\ $ to be closed because if $\ X=\mathbb{R},\ $ then $\ A = [0,1) \cup (2,3]\ $ is not closed, is convex but is not connected.

I'm not even sure I can prove this if $\ X = \mathbb{R},\ $ although I do know that the closed subsets of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $ are the unions of Cantor sets and closed intervals. But I was actually hoping for a more general, possibly topological approach to the question anyway....

Edit: [Here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convex.html#:%7E:text=A%20set%20in%20Euclidean%20space%20is%20convex%20set,convex%2C%20implying%20pathwise-connected%2C%20which%20in%20turn%20implies%20connected.) it says that a convex set is always star convex, implying pathwise-connected, which in turn implies connected.

Edit: I have a further question: is $\ A\ $ complete? And I am also not sure if, more generally, a closed connected set in a m.s. is complete? Clearly though, closed and complete does not imply connected, e.g. $ [0,1]\cup [2,3].$ Edit: DanielWainfleet answered this in the comments. The answer is no, e.g. $\ X = A = (0,1]\ $ so yes, the underlying metric space is important.

Comment: I think what you wrote is the definition of polygonal connectedness.  But a polygonal connected space is connected only if $X$ is a normed linear space.  With that said, I think it's a pretty good question.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a purely topological approach, simply because you're using an essentially metric property. I think I know what you mean, though: something with the "flavor" of general topology.

Comment: Wait, isn't the union of two disjoint closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ a counterexample?

Comment: Shall I change my question to what I originally intended it to be (the ordered inbetweenness property of $\ \mathbb{R})\ $ or is it too late for that and I should post a new question?

Comment: You would need to fix the inbetweenness property as well as require completeness. Without completeness, the rationals would provide a counter-example.

Comment: @JohnDouma the rationals are not closed though?

Comment: The rationals would be $X$. In that case, they are closed. Then we could take $A$ to be either the whole set or the set of rationals between $-5$ and $5$ inclusive. That set could further be partitioned into two sets, one of which is such that the rationals are greater than the square root of two and one which is less.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah that's true.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs. The union $X= [0,1]\cup [2,3]$ is not a counter-example because $d(1,2)=1$ but if $x\in X$ and $1\ne x\ne 2$ then $d(1,x)+d(x,2)>1.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet please don’t take too much notice of previous comments, as I changed the question after these comments were made.

Comment: Intuitively I think there should be a counter-example with $A=X$ but I have not got one. On your further Q's, if A  is closed and X is complete then A is complete. And a closed connected subset of X need not be complete if X is not complete, e.g. A=X=(0,1].

Comment: It's true for $X=\Bbb R$.  If $\emptyset \ne A=\bar A\subsetneqq \Bbb R$  then $\Bbb R\setminus A=\cup F$ where $F$ is a pairwise-disjoint family of non-empty convex open sets. Now if $A $ is not a half-line nor a bounded interval then there exists some bounded $J\in F.$ But if $a_1=\inf J$ and $a_2=\sup J$ then there is no $y\in A\setminus \{a_1,a_2\}$ with $|a_1-y|+|y-a_2|=|a_1-a_2|$ as this requires $y\in (a_1,a_2)=J\subseteqq \Bbb R\setminus A.$

Comment: I can also prove it for $X=\Bbb R^n$ with $n\in\Bbb N$ and the Cartesian metric by applying the case $n=1$ and the fact that if $a,b,c$ are 3 points in $\Bbb R^n$ with $d(a,b)+d(b,c)=d(a,c)$ then $b\in \{ra+(1-r)b: 0<r<1\}$ to show that $A$ is convex, hence path-connected, hence connected.

Comment: Star-convex is only a notion in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or similar topological spaces). For example, the unit circle $S^1$ is convex, if you regard it as its own topologic space, where distance is measured as the "length of the shortest arc segment, connecting the two points"

Comment: @tomasz What metric will you give  on the topologist's sine curve? If you use the straightline metric in $\Bbb{R}^2$, then it is not metric-convex since there exists lines intersecting the curve only at two points where the convexity fails; If you use the length metric, how can you define the distance of a point on the function curve and a point on the vertical segment?

Comment: @tomasz The problem happens everywhere, not only the coarse end. For example, convexity fails at two consecutive zeroes of your function -- in fact it fails whenever there is a line intersecting the graph with a pair of adjacent isolated points when you use the straightline metric of the ambient space.

Comment: @Zerox Right. I was thinking of not having any two points without a third point on a line through them, but that is obviously not what's needed. My bad.

Comment: You are using a very nonstandard definition of convexity here, the standard one (due to Menger) is that for each pair of points $x, y\in A$, there is a midpoint $z\in A$, $d(x,z)=d(z,y)=d(x,y)/2$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It can't be *that* nonstandard as it's the definition from wikipedia... anyway, that's not a contentious point, and you can use whatever definition you want...

Answer (score 7):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A *geodesic* (the word "geodesic" here is a noun) in $X$ is the image of an isometric map
$$
f: I\to X,
$$
where $I$ is an interval in ${\mathbb R}$.
A metric space is called *geodesic* (the word "geodesic" here is an adjective) if every two points belong to a common geodesic. Such a space is necessarily path-connected and, hence, connected.

Proposition. Suppose that $(X,d)$ is complete and convex in the sense of your question. Then $(X,d)$ is a geodesic metric space.

Proof. Take two points $x,y\in X$, $D=d(x,y)$. Consider the set $S$ of isometric maps $f: A\to X$, where $A\subset I=[0,D]$ contains $0, D$ and $f(0)=x, f(D)=y$. Define a partial order on $S$ by:
$$
(f: A\to X)\le (g: B\to X) \iff A\subseteq B, f=g|_A.
$$

Zorn's lemma implies that $S$ contains at least one maximal element, i.e. $(f: A\to X)\in S$ such that if  $(f: A\to X)\le (g: B\to X)$, then $A=B$. (**Caveat:** I am assuming the Axiom of Choice here. I leave it to somebody else to worry about the dependence of validity of the Proposition on the Axiom of Choice.)

Our goal is to prove that for such a maximal element $(f: A\to X)$, $A=I=[0,D]$ (then we would be done).

1. First, I will prove that for each maximal element $(f: A\to X)$, $A$ is a closed subset of $I$. Indeed, take a sequence $t_n\in A$, $t_n\to t\notin A$. Then $(t_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, hence, its image $(f(t_n))$ is also Cauchy, hence, by completeness, converges to some $z\in X$. Then we extend $f$ to the point $t$ by $f(t)=z$. The same argument with Cauchy sequences implies that the extended map is continuous at $t$. By continuity of the extension, the new map $f: B=A\cup \{z\}\to X$ is still isometric, hence, $(f: A\to X)< (f: B\to X)$, contradicting maximality of $(f: A\to X)$.
2. Suppose that $A\ne I$. Then the complement $I\setminus A$ is a nonempty union of open intervals; take one of these intervals $J=(a,b)$, where $a, b\in A$. By convexity of $(X,d)$, there exists a point $z\in X$ such that $d(f(a), z)+d(z, f(b))=d(f(a), f(b))$ and $z\notin \{f(a), f(b)\}$. Take
   $t\in [a,b]$ such that $|t-a|=d(f(a), z)$ and extend $f$ to $t$ by $f(t)=z$. I leave it to you to check that the extended map
   $$
   f: B=A\cup \{t\}\to X
   $$
   is still isometric. Since $A\ne B$, we obtain a contradiction with maximality of $(f: A\to X)$. qed

Comment: This is a simple but excellent answer!

Comment: (+1) Damn, this looks way better than the long answer (also using Zorn's lemma) that I've been toiling over for the last three days!

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer.
We prove that $A$ is connected when $A$ is compact by contradiction:
Suppose $A$ is not connected, which means $A = A_1 \cup A_2$ where $A_1,A_2$ are disjoint closed subsets of $A$. Then $A_1,A_2$ are themselves compact. Consider $d:A_1 \times A_2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^+: (p,q) \mapsto d(p,q)$, then $d$ is a continuous function on a compact space, thus achieving its non-zero minimum at $(p_0,q_0) \; (p_0 \ne q_0)$.
Since A is convex, there exists $x \in A \backslash \{ p_0,q_0 \}$ such that $d(p_0,q_0) = d(p_0,x)+d(x,q_0)$, in particular $d(p_0,x)<d(p_0,q_0)$ and $d(x,q_0)<d(p_0,q_0)$. However, $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \Rightarrow x\in A_1$ or $x \in A_2$, either of which contradicts the assumption that $d$ achieves its minimum at $(p_0,q_0)$.

Notice that the proof above doesn't use the completeness of $X$, and by the comment of *tomasz* what actually matters is the completeness of $A$.

Comment: If the distance function is a coercive function, then the result also follows for A not bounded, because coercive functions achives minimum on any closed set.

Comment: @R.W.Prado Coercivity is defined by the distance function. In what sense can we say the distance function "coercive"?

Comment: That's not the problem, its quite easy to generalize. Take a point and think define to be coercive If the function explodes for points far from that point. I'm thinking about another detail. I need that bounded sequences converges in such space. That's not easy to deal with It, unless you compactifies the space or something.

Comment: A good definition for coercive function relatively to a set A that is good for your case would be: for every positive M, there exist a compact set C such that for every point outside C and in A, say x, implies f(x)>M. For this new type of coercive, If the distance is coercive, your proof works. This definition could be used to generalize your proof, since all distances are coercive functions relatively to compact sets.

Comment: "If $A$ is compact... and not connected, this means $A = A_1 \cup A_2$ where $A_1,A_2$ are disjoint closed subsets of $A$. " To be honest, even this is not obvious to me. Please can you explain why this is true?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I think this is the topological definition of "disconnectedness".

Comment: I got your problem. Just define the coercive function to be $f:A_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=d(x,A_2)$. This function is almost always coercive, when $A_2$ is bounded (take one, If necessary), and is almost like yours

Comment: @Zerox the definition of connectedness I am aware of is the one from Rudin's PMA: $A$ and $B$ are *separated* if $A \cap  \overline B \ $  and $ \  \overline A \cap  B \ $ are empty. Then $ \ A \ $ is *connected* if $ \ A \ $ is not the union of two nonempty separated sets. But I'm guessing this definition and the definition you are alluding to are equivalent.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Well if $A$ and $B$ are separated and $X=A \cup B$, then since $\overline A \cap B = \varnothing$, $\overline A \subseteq B^C = A \subseteq \overline A$, which means $A = \overline A$ and thus $A$ is closed. The same for $B$.

Comment: @Zerox Ah ok, very nice. So if $ \ X = A \cup B \ $ and $ \ A \ $ and $\ B\ $ are separated, then $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are closed in $\ X\ $ and therefore $\ X\ $ is the union of two nonempty separated (and therefore disjoint) closed sets. So this is where the first line comes from (from my perspective).

Answer (score 2):

Because $A$ is a closed convex subspace of a complete metric space,
$A$ is a complete convex metric space.  We show that any complete
convex metric space $A$ is path-connected, and therefore connected.
(The properties of convexity and completeness will not be used until
near the end of the argument, so most results hold for an arbitrary
metric space $A.$)

The proof uses the
[Hausdorff maximal principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_maximal_principle),
which is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice (and to Zorn's lemma).

For any metric space $(A, d)$ the function
$d \colon A \times A \to [0, \infty)$ is (uniformly) continuous,
therefore for every pair of points $a, b \in A,$ the function
$$
f_{a, b} \colon A \to [0, \infty), \
x \mapsto d(a, x) + d(x, b) - d(a, b)
$$
is continuous, therefore the set
$$
[[a, b]] = [[b, a]] = f_{a, b}^{-1}(0) =
\{x \in A : d(a, x) + d(x, b) = d(a, b)\}
$$
is closed in $A.$

**Lemma 1.** For all $w, x, y, z \in A,$
$$
(z \in [[x, y]] \text{ and } w \in [[x, z]]) \iff
(w \in [[x, y]] \text{ and } z \in [[w, y]]).
$$

*Proof.* Forward implication: if $z \in [[x, y]]$ and
$w \in [[x, z]],$ then
\begin{multline*}
d(x, y) = d(x, z) + d(z, y) = d(x, w) + d(w, z) + d(z, y) \\
\geqslant d(x, w) + d(w, y) \geqslant d(x, y),
\end{multline*}
therefore $d(x, z) + d(z, y) = d(x, y)$ and
$d(w, z) + d(z, y) = d(w, y),$ i.e.,
$w \in [[x, y]]$ and $z \in [[w, y]].$

In view of the symmetry of the $[[a, b]]$ notation, the converse
implication is just the same quantified proposition, in which the
bound variables $(x, w, z, y)$ have been replaced by $(y, z, w, x)$
respectively; and so it is also true. $\ \square$

**Lemma 2.** For every pair of points $a, b \in A,$ the set
$\{x \in A : b \in [[a, x]]\}$ is closed in $A.$

*Proof.* The set in question is equal to $g_{a, b}^{-1}(0),$
where
$$
g_{a, b} \colon A \to [0, \infty), \
x \mapsto d(a, b) + d(b, x) - d(a, x).
$$
It is closed because $g_{a, b}$ is continuous. $ \ \square$

**Corollary 3.** For every pair of points $a, b \in A,$ the set
$[[a, b]] \cup \{x \in A : b \in [[a, x]]\}$ is closed in $A.$
$ \ \square$

The functions $f_{a, b}$ and $g_{a, b}$ were only of temporary use,
but we will be making much use of the continuous function
$$
d_a \colon A \to [0, \infty), \ x \mapsto d(a, x),
$$
which is defined for each point $a \in A.$ For each point $a \in A$
we also define a binary relation $\leqslant_a$ on $A,$ thus:
$$
x \leqslant_a y \iff x \in [[a, y]] \quad (x, y \in A).
$$

**Lemma 4.** The relation $\leqslant_a$ is a partial order on
$A.$

*Proof.* Trivially, $x \in [[a, x]],$ so $\leqslant_a$ is
reflexive.  Next, suppose $x \in [[a, y]]$ and $y \in [[a, x]].$
Then
$$
d(x, y) = d(a, y) - d(a, x) = -(d(a, x) - d(a, y)) = -d(x, y),
$$
therefore $d(x, y) = 0,$ therefore $x = y$; so $\leqslant_a$ is
antisymmetric.  Finally, suppose $x \in [[a, y]]$ and
$y \in [[a, z]].$ Then Lemma 1 gives $x \in [[a, z]]$ (also
$y \in [[x, z]]$); so $\leqslant_a$ is transitive. $ \ \square$

**Lemma 5.** For each point $a \in A,$ the function
$d_a \colon (A, \leqslant_a) \to [0, \infty),$ $x \mapsto d(a, x)$
is order-preserving (isotone).

*Proof.* If $x \leqslant_a y,$ then
$$
d_a(x) = d(a, x) = d(a, y) - d(x, y) \leqslant d(a, y) = d_a(y).
\quad \square
$$

Applying standard conventions from order theory, we can write
expressions such as "$x <_a y$", meaning $x \leqslant_a y$ and
$x \ne y,$ or "$x \geqslant_a y$", meaning $y \leqslant_a x,$ or
"$x >_a y$", meaning $y <_a x.$

Recall also that a totally ordered subset of an ordered set is
called a *chain.*

**Lemma 6.** If $S$ is a chain in $(A, \leqslant_a),$ then the
function $d_a \colon A \to [0, \infty),$ $x \mapsto d(a, x)$
restricts to an isometry $d_a|_S \colon S \to [0, \infty).$ That is:
$$
|d_a(x) - d_a(y)| = d(x, y) \text{ for all } x, y \in S.
$$

*Proof.* For all $x, y \in S,$ we have either
$x \in [[a, y]],$ in which case $d(x, y) = d_a(y) - d_a(x),$ or
$y \in [[a, x]],$ in which case $d(x, y) = d_a(x) - d_a(y).$
$\ \square$

**Corollary 7.** If $S$ is a chain in $(A, \leqslant_a),$ then
for all $x, y \in S$:
\begin{gather*}
x = y \iff d_a(x) = d_a(y), \\
x \leqslant_a y \iff d_a(x) \leqslant d_a(y), \\
x <_a y \iff d_a(x) < d_a(y).
\end{gather*}

*Proof.* The function $d_a$ is injective because it is an
isometry.  The equivalence of $x \leqslant_a y$ with
$d_a(x) \leqslant d_a(y),$ and of $x <_a y$ with $d_a(x) < d_a(y),$
follows from the injectivity of $d_a$ and the fact that $S$ is
totally ordered. $ \ \square$

**Lemma 8.** If $a, x, y \in A$ and $x \leqslant_a y,$ then
$$
[[x, y]] = \{z \in A : x \leqslant_a z \leqslant_a y\}.
$$

*Proof.* By Lemma 1, if $x \in [[a, y]]$ and $z \in [[x, y]]$
then $x \in [[a, z]]$ and $z \in [[a, y]].$ This proves that
$[[x, y]] \subseteq \{z \in A : x \leqslant_a z \leqslant_a y\}.$

Also by Lemma 1, if $z \in [[a, y]]$ and $x \in [[a, z]]$ then
$z \in [[x, y]]$ (and $x \in [[a, y]]$). This proves that
$\{z \in A : x \leqslant_a z \leqslant_a y\} \subseteq [[x, y]].$
$\ \square$

**Lemma 9.** For all $a, b \in A,$ and all $x, y \in [[a, b]],$
$$
x \leqslant_a y \text{ if and only if } y \leqslant_b x.
$$

*Proof.* By Lemma 1, if $y \in [[a, b]]$ and $x \in [[a, y]],$
then $y \in [[b, x]].$ Also by Lemma 1, if $x \in [[b, a]]$ and
$y \in [[b, x]]$ then $x \in [[y, a]]. \ \square$

By Lemma 9, for every pair of points $a, b \in A,$ the chains of
$([[a, b]], \leqslant_a)$ are the same as the chains of
$([[a, b]], \leqslant_b).$ A set $S \subseteq [[a, b]]$ is a chain
if and only if for all $x, y \in S,$ $x \in [[a, y]]$ or
$y \in [[a, x]].$

Now let points $a, b \in A$ (not necessarily distinct) be chosen and
kept fixed for the rest of the argument.  We will usually work with
the relation $\leqslant_a$ on $[[a, b]],$ rather than $\leqslant_b.$
We write $d(a, b) = \rho \geqslant 0,$ and abuse notation slightly
by restricting the domain and codomain of $d_a,$ so that now
$d_a \colon [[a, b]] \to [0, \rho].$

**Lemma 10.** If $S$ is a chain in $([[a, b]], \leqslant_a),$
then so is its closure, $\overline{S}.$

*Proof.* Suppose $S$ is a chain.  For all $x \in S$ and all
$y \in S$ we have
\begin{equation}
\label{4366228:eq:1b}\tag{1}
y \in [[a, x]] \cup \{y \in A : y \in [[a, z]]\}.
\end{equation}
By Corollary 3, the set on the right-hand side of
\eqref{4366228:eq:1b} is closed.  Therefore, it contains the limits
of all convergent sequences of points in $S.$ That is,
\eqref{4366228:eq:1b} also holds for all $x \in S$ and all
$y \in \overline{S}.$ Equivalently, for all such $x$ and $y,$
$$
x \in [[a, y]] \cup \{x \in A : y \in [[a, x]]\}.
$$
By the same argument, it follows that for all $x \in \overline{S}$
and all $y \in \overline{S},$ $x \in [[a, y]]$ or $y \in [[a, x]]$;
that is, $\overline{S}$ is a chain in
$([[a, b]], \leqslant_a). \ \square$

(One could argue more concisely that $S$ is a chain if and only if
$S \times S \subseteq B,$ where $B$ is a closed subset of
$A \times A,$ defined like $f_{a, b}^{-1}(0)$ and $g_{a, b}^{-1}(0)$
above; but the argument's conciseness would probably be offset by
heavy use of notation.)

By the Hausdorff maximal principle, the ordered set
$([[a, b]], \leqslant_a)$ contains a maximal chain. (Indeed, every
chain in an ordered set is contained in a maximal chain.) From now
on, let $S$ be a maximal chain in $([[a, b]], \leqslant_a).$

**Lemma 11.** $S$ is closed in $A.$

*Proof.* This follows from Lemma 10 together with the maximality
of $S. \ \square$

**Lemma 12.** $\{a, b\} \subseteq S.$

*Proof.* Let $S' = S \cup \{a, b\}.$ We have $b \in [[a, b]],$
and for all $x \in S,$ $a \in [[a, x]]$ and $x \in [[a, b]].$ Hence
$S'$ is a chain in $[[a, b]].$ But $S$ is maximal, therefore
$S' = S,$ therefore $\{a, b\} \subseteq S. \ \square$

We establish the path-connectedness of $A$ by constructing a
bijective isometry $\gamma\colon[0, \rho] \to S$ such that
$\gamma(0) = a$ and $\gamma(\rho) = b.$ It is enough to show that
the isometry $d_a|_S \colon S \to [0, \rho]$ from Lemma 6 (with the
newly restricted codomain) is surjective, therefore bijective; then
we can take $\gamma = (d_a|_S)^{-1}.$

Let $\tau$ be any real number such that
$0 \leqslant \tau \leqslant \rho.$ Then $S = L \cup R,$ where
\begin{align*}
L & = \{x \in S : \ d_a(x) \leqslant \tau\}, \\
R & = \{y \in S : \ d_a(y) \geqslant \tau\}.
\end{align*}
Neither of these closed subsets of $A$ is empty, because $a \in L$
and $b \in R.$ Define
\begin{gather*}
\xi  = \sup(d_a(L)) \in [0, \tau], \\
\eta = \inf(d_a(R)) \in [\tau, \rho].
\end{gather*}

We prove first that there exist $x \in L$ such that
$d_a(x) = \xi,$ and $y \in R$ such that $d_a(y) = \eta.$
To this end, choose sequences $(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ in $L$ and
$(y_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ in $R$ such that $\lim_nd_a(x_n) = \xi$
and $\lim_nd_a(y_n) = \eta.$ Because
$d_a|_S \colon S \to [0, \rho]$ is an isometry, and
$(d_a(x_n))$ and $(d_a(y_n))$ are Cauchy sequences in
$[0, \rho],$ the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy in $S.$
Therefore, because the metric space $A$ is complete, and the subsets
$L$ and $R$ are closed, the limit $x = \lim_nx_n$ exists in $L,$ and
the limit $y = \lim_ny_n$ exists in $R$ (abusing notation slightly).
Because $d_a$ is continuous,
\begin{align*}
d_a(x) & = \lim_nd_a(x_n) = \xi, \\
d_a(y) & = \lim_nd_a(y_n) = \eta.
\end{align*}

We have $d_a(x) \leqslant d_a(y),$ whence by Corollary 7,
$x \leqslant_a y.$ By the convexity of $A,$ if $x \ne y,$ then there
exists $z \in A$ such that $z \in [[x, y]]$ and $z \ne x$ and
$z \ne y.$ By Lemma 8, $x <_a z <_a y.$ By Corollary 7 again, for
all $w \in S$ we have either (i) $w \leqslant_a x <_a z,$ whence
$w \in [[a, z]],$ or (ii) $z <_a y \leqslant_a w,$ whence
$z \in [[a, w]].$ Therefore $S \cup \{z\}$ is a chain in
$([[a, b]], \leqslant_a).$ Because $S$ is maximal, it follows that
$z \in S.$ But this is a contradiction, because it has just been
shown that for all $w \in S,$ either $w <_a z$ or $z <_a w$.
Therefore, the hypothesis $x \ne y$ is false, i.e., $x = y.$
Therefore $\xi = \eta.$ But $\xi \leqslant \tau \leqslant \eta,$
therefore $d_a(x) = \tau = d_a(y).$ So $d_a|_S$ is surjective, and
the proof is complete.

Comment: "four days' hard work". Hopefully you yourself learned something then? Also, I once spent like 2 months trying to prove something in quantum mechanics and failed to do so, so don't feel too bad...

Comment: Rest on the seventh day? Sounds biblical... but yeah that's a long proof. Well don't for persevering!